# Embedding External Javascript into a Shopify Liquid File to edit a specific div

Tags: javascript, html, shopify, liquid

First time poster here. I'm still fairly new to shopify & computer science overall, so please bear with me.

I'm trying to update a banner so it rotates between 3 text messages. Here's the JS and HTML I wrote. Note that the JS file is located under assets.

```js
    var banner = document.getElementById("discountbanner");
    setInterval(bannerupdate, 3000);

    function bannerupdate(){
      for(i=1; i != 0; i++)
      {
        switch(i%2){
          case 0:
              banner.innerHTML = "Preorder now for 10% off!";
              break;
          case 1:
              banner.setAttribute("href", "xyz.com");
              banner.innerHTML = "Buy More, Save More: Save up to 30% today!";
              break;
          case 2:
            banner.innerHTML = "Free Shipping on orders of $750+";
            break;
        }
       }
    }
```

```html
         <div id="discountbanner">
            {% assign pricegoal = cart.items_subtotal_price | divided_by: 100 %}
            {% if pricegoal == 0 %}
                <!--embed JS here-->
             {% elsif pricegoal < 3000 %}
           <a href="xyz.com" title="Click here to learn more!">Spend only ${{ 3000 | minus: pricegoal }} more to save 20%!</a>
            {% elsif pricegoal == 3000 %} 
           <a href="xyz.com" title="Click here to learn more!">You saved 20% on this order! Spend an extra $1500 and save an extra 10%!</a>
            {% elsif pricegoal > 3000 and pricegoal < 4500 %}
           <a href="xyz.com" title="Click here to learn more!">You've saved 20%! Spend only ${{ 4500 | minus: pricegoal }} more to save 30%!</a>
            {% elsif pricegoal > 4500 %}
            You got 30% off your order!
            {% endif %}
          </div>
```

The end goal is to have the banner only rotate if a customer hasn't added anything to their cart. When I embed the js using
`{{'banner.js' | asset_url | script_tag}}`
as well as
`<script src = "{{'banner.js | asset_url | script_tag}}"></script>`

The latter doesn't seem to work, though the former causes an infinite loop, which it theoretically should, but that causes the page to load infinitely and never display the rest of the content.

Furthermore, even if I do the js inline, it's still not updating properly. Any thoughts on how to fix this?

I'm guessing it has to do with the js.

Comment: Hi @kc99 I think you need to utilize the theme code, your theme has surely any slider or carousel library, you simply use the same to create a text rotation into the theme.

Comment: This is the correct way `{{ 'banner.js' | asset_url | script_tag }}`, there is nothing wrong into it.

Comment: If you want to add using `script` tag then syntax is like this one, `<script src = "{{'banner.js | asset_url }}"></script>`. you not use `script_tag` only file name and asset_url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like your JS code is not correct.

```
var i = 0;
var textArray = [
"Preorder now for 10% off!",
"Buy More, Save More: Save up to 30% today!",
"Free Shipping on orders of $750+"
];

 setInterval(()=>{
  banner.innerHTML = textArray[i%3];
  i++;
 }, 3000);
```